# Jupyter lab: why variable on single line does not generate output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I follow a tutorial about Jupyter and Python, where it says that if two consecutive commands are the following:

```
in: x = 2
in: x
```

I should get

```
out: 2
```

as an result. However, the x on single line in a combined block like:

```
in: x = 2
in: if x == 2:
       x
```

does not print the x variable. Is this x on single line somewhat different from x as a single command? When I write this I see, a line is different as whole command but what is the underlying concept or thing that makes the first two commands result 2 but the second three commands nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the difference between an [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) and a statement (see below for links) in python.

An expression can only contain [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers), [literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) and [operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators).

Statements can be significantly more complex. See [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) and [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html)

The python shell will output the evaluation of an expression, but won't with a statement because there's no guarantee it evaluates to something that can be outputted. You should use `print` to output values from a statement.

Consider what would happen if you replaced `x` with its value (`2`):

```
if 2 == 2:
    2
```

Would you expect the interpreter to output `2`?

Answer (score 1):

When you write a variable in a line and execute it jupyter notebook assumes that you want to know the value of the variable and implicitly converts it to print(variable) so the value of the variable is printed.

When you use multiple statement you will rarely want to print all variables used in the statements. So it is not implemented for this case